# Aggregation Tables with less data than facts table - Is it a problem?

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I've recently enter the big data BI world and have a very specific question.

**This is my model:**

[image: data model]

I have a **fact table with last 4 years (2020-2023)** of data (2 billion rows) and an **aggregated table with the last 2 years (2022-2023)** of data (20M rows). So, the aggregated table as less years of data than the facts table.

When I use the date slicer and pick a date prior to 2022, I get a **blank visual because the measure always hits the AGG** (which does not have data for this time period) and not the facts table as expected. Have you guys faced a common issue? Is there a workaround?

**The dax measure:**

```
measure =
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT(cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[article]),
        cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[is_unique] = 1
    )
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the DAX expression for your measure? (Update your question above with it).

Comment: @SamNseir udpated

Comment: Note that if the "agg" table doesn't aggregate all the data in the fact table you _should not_ register it as a user-defined aggregate table.  You can have it in the model and refer to it in measures, or separate visuals.  But it's not really what Power BI considers an Aggregate Table.

Answer (score 1):

The aggregated table by default doesn't contain data for dates prior to 2022 that's why you have blank visuals for earlier dates.

```
  Measure =
    VAR SelectedStartDate = MIN('Date'[Date])  
    VAR SelectedEndDate = MAX('Date'[Date])    
    VAR UseAggregatedTable = SelectedStartDate >= DATE(2022, 1, 1) && SelectedEndDate <= DATE(2023, 12, 31)
    RETURN
        IF(
            UseAggregatedTable,
            CALCULATE(
                COUNT(cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[article]),
                cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[is_unique] = 1
            ),
            CALCULATE(
                COUNT(factTable[article]),  
                factTable[is_unique] = 1
            )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this approach before, but it will hit the AGG table all the same.

Comment: Is it possible to share your pbix file ?

Answer (score 0):

I've come to a workaround, mainly because, as far as I could understand the engine does not work how I imagined it.

Your aggregation table must encompass the full dataset of the facts table. Even though the engine is very good, he's not able of switching between AGG and Facts table, if the AGG does not have all of the required timeframe.

The solution was to create a data model based on a hot and cold direct query:

[image]

The HOT DQ will encompass data from the last 2 years, while the COLD DQ will encompass data prior to the last 2 years.

I've had to make a few adjustments on the measures I've created, for example:

```
Measure =
    DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(
            COUNT(HOT_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[article]),
            HOT_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[has_discount] = 1
            ),
        CALCULATE(COUNT(HOT_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[article]))
    )
    +
    IF(
        MIN(Dim_Calendar[date]) < [_min_updated_date],
        DIVIDE(
        CALCULATE(
            COUNT(COLD_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[article]),
            COLD_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[has_discount] = 1
            ),
        CALCULATE(COUNT(COLD_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[article]))
    )
    )
```

The measure containing the _threshold_date, required to evaluate if the consulting of the COLD DQ is required:

```
_threshold_date = 
    CALCULATE(
                MIN(HOT_cci_gpmt_ecommerce_global[report_date]),
                ALL(Dim_Calendar)
            )
```

This way:

- if the user selects the last 2 years, the AGG is hit;
- if the user selects a timeframe prior to the last 2 years, the COLD DQ is hit;
- if the user selects a timeframe encompassing the last 4 years (for instance), both the AGG and COLD DQ are hit.

Hope i was able to explain it well, and thank you for the help!